# blockly How to build blockpy locally?

Tags: python, blockly

I want to build blockpy locally, so I build based on [this](https://github.com/blockpy-edu/blockpy).
After construction, only Python code can be generated through blocks, but blocks cannot be generated through Python code.

[image: This is the result after I built locally]

I am searching for a long time on net. But no use. Please help or try to give some ideas how to achieve this.

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please provide some detail on what you have tried. Do you have any error messages?

Comment: Blockly does not provide a method for Python to generate blockly. But it has been implemented. You can refer to microbit to write it. https://makecode.microbit.org/